# Map.setCenter sometimes causes OutOfMemory crashes

Tags: android, here-api

Once in a while, I get OutOfMemoryException when calling Map.setCenter.

Stack Trace :

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
at java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList.add(CopyOnWriteArrayList.java:267)
at com.nokia.maps.MapImpl.a(MapImpl.java:587)
at com.nokia.maps.MapImpl.a(MapImpl.java:2939)
at com.here.android.mpa.mapping.Map.setCenter(Map.java:865)
at com.cirrios.smartnavigationlib.ui.MapController$1.run(MapController.java:84)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:801)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:617)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I'm using Here Premium SDK v3.3.0

Any clue on how to prevent this ?

Comment: Would you be able to provide some additional context on what is happening in your app when you see this issue? e.g. Are you making many calls to the `Map` in a short period of time? Do you have multiple `Map`s in use in your application? Ideally, some minimal sample code to reproduce this issue would be helpful. Also, if you could grab a HPROF and post a screenshot of the suspect reference tree it would be helpful [HPROF Viewer and Analyzer](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/am-hprof.html)

Comment: Sadly this only happened on production devices and were reported to me via Acra. I'm not able to reproduce it. I'm using only one Map. This "setCenter" method is called every 250 millis in a runnable task (to follow vehicle)

Answer (score 1):

It's possible what is happening here is that your periodic task to call `setCenter()` is somehow running at a time when the `Map` is not being displayed/drawn.

These `setCenter()` events are added to a task queue which is only flushed on every `Map` draw, so if many are being added with no draw call it could casue this OOM issue. The SDK could clear old events if they would be cancelled by new ones to prevent this, it's something we can look into.

In the meantime, one idea to prevent this if the theory is correct would be to register an `OnMapRenderListener` with the `MapFragment` and listen for `onPostDraw()` callbacks. You can use a thread safe flag (e.g. `AtomicBoolean`) to indicate a draw has occurred since your last `setCenter()` call and only call `setCenter()` again if this is true (you would flip the flag in your `setCenter` `Runnable`).

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that and see if I still get the issue.